# How do I get around this issue with GWT compiler

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt-compiler

I get this error when I try to compile a program with very long classpath in Eclipse with GWT compiler.

> Cannot run program "...java"  ... java.io.IOException: error=7, Argument list too long

Could only find [one reference](http://www.mail-archive.com/google-web-toolkit@googlegroups.com/msg23206.html) on web.

Comment: Note: This is probably not related to gwt. It just happens, that the gwt compiler is a Java application, and sometimes requires a long argument list, because it's a compiler. Please post your java call (are you using ant?), and double-check, if you really need all the libraries you're including in your classpath.

Comment: @Chris is right, this is not a GWT problem. This is a problem with your build tool, supplying too many command-line arguments to the GWT compiler.

Comment: This is on Redhat Linux, Eclipse. I am using the Google plugin for eclipse to compile the project. I can not get rid of any of the dependencies, all of them are required. I am going to try compiling it using ant target and see what happens. However, Eclipse's GWT compile is convenient. It would be good if I can get that working.

Comment: A not recommended way to solve that is to package all (or most of) your dependencies in a single jar file to shrink the number of files in the classpath, and thus reducing the arguments to the compiler.